# Create a Multiples function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a test to fulfill. The requirement is

> It should accept two parameters, the first being the limit and the second being an array of multiples that will be included in the sum. e.g. multiples of 3 and 5 that are less than 10 would be checked using Multiples(10,[3,5]). If no multiples are defined, a default of three and five should be used.

This is what I got so far

```
function multiples(a, b) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) {
      sum += i;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

but is still not validate the test...

Any help will be highly appreciated..

Comment: Which test cases fail? One thing that is certainly strange is that you are not doing anything with `b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`

```js
function multiples(a, b) {
   let sum = 0;
   for (let i = 0; i < a; i++) {
      for(let j of b){
          if (i % j === 0) {
             sum += i;break;
           }
      }
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(multiples(10,[3,5]))//23;
```

Hi, please check this one.In the logic **break** should be used in the inner for loop.since if you give range 20, number 15 will be added for two times because 15 is multiple of 3 & 5.

Comment: Thank you this one with a small adjustment passed all tests. I do apologise for noob stupid question but I have only 5 weeks of JS....still finding my way around...

Answer (score 1):

You're hard-coding the 3 and 5 values instead of using what is passed in with `b`.

Something like this may be closer to the mark

```
function multiples(a, b = [3,5]) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < b.length; k++) {
        if (i % b[k] === 0) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

This code will iterate through the array defined by `b` and test each value that has been passed in.

If no value for `b` is included in the method call, the `b = [3,5]` in the signature will ensure that an array of 3 and 5 are used as a default.